# Estimator of an unknown distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I came across this distribution,

$$\left(\begin{smallmatrix} x & - & 1\\ n & - & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right) p^n(1-p)^{x-n}. \hspace{1cm}x=n, n+1,...,$$

Initially, it looked like Binomial Distribution but when I started working out, I found out that it is not Binomial distribution. After some googling, I think it is hypo-geometric distribution. I'm not sure though.

i) What distribution is this function?

ii) What is the estimator of this function? Should I apply Log-Likelihood or Maximum Likelihood?

Comment: This is a negative binomial distribution, it's just that the labeling of the "states" is shifted compared to the usual definition.

Comment: [Look at the second alternative definition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Alternative_formulations)

Comment: "Estimator of a function" makes no sense.  An estimator is a function of a random sample that provides information about one or more *parameters* of a distribution.  As such your question is vague.  Which parameter(s) are you estimating and what function(s) of those parameters are you interested in?